# Reading/writing a file containing newlines by newlines

Tags: python, python-3.x, database

So, I have a program that attempts to write a data list with data in the format of
`string,hash\n`.
This works fine for most of my cases, but some of the data contains a newline character in the string, meaning that my program to read it gets caught on it and mangles the data. How can I either

1. Separate this data (it contains all possible 3 character long string permutations)
2. Ignore all but the newlines at the end of the data used to separate the data.

Here's my reader code:

```
table = []
with open(target, "r") as file:
    f = file.readlines()
    print(f)
    for item in f:
        print(item)
        string = item.rstrip("\n").split(",")
        print(string)
        hash = string[1]
        string = string[0]
    table.append(hashpair(string,hash))
    return table
```

I've tried to use different methods of separating the data, but because the string contains all characters, I can't separate it by any character. Encoding it would be too much of a performance hit (it would actually be more time efficient to not store the data and just recompile it every single time).

Comment: If the data contains literal newlines, you need to define some way to escape them, and check for this in your code. Otherwise how is the code supposed to know which newlines are literal and which are line separators?

Comment: Can you fix the code that creates the file so that it uses CSV format? This puts quotes around fields that contain the delimiter. Then you can read it with the `csv` module and it will parse that properly.

Answer (score 0):

As was mentioned before, this would be something that is more easily accomplished using something like the csv library. [GeeksForGeeks](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/reading-and-writing-csv-files-in-python/) has a good tutorial on writing and reading with the csv library.

If you're really dedicated to doing straight file read/writes the you might try wrapping the fields in quotes in a way similar to how the csv module functions. However, this would require significantly more work than using a prebuilt module like csv.